# Opening pdf using Acrobat Javascript on Apple

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I would like to open a pdf document using Javascript in Acrobat Pro DC running OSX. Here's what I see:

```
app.openDoc("~/Desktop/test.pdf")
Invalid Location "~/Desktop/test.pdf". File or folder does not exist.
NotAllowedError: Security settings prevent access to this property or method.
App.openDoc:1:Console undefined:Exec
undefined
```

I wonder whether the error is the security restrictions mentioned on [page 135 of the Javascript for Acrobat reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/AcrobatDC_js_api_reference.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Acrobat JavaScript is cross-platform, you need to use device independent paths and you can't use device-specific shortcuts like "~". Something like the examples below.

Windows Path C:\MyFolder\MyFile.pdf

```
app.openDoc("/C/MyFolder/MyFile.pdf");
```

Macintosh path MyDisk:MyFolder:MyFile.pdf

```
app.openDoc("/MyDisk/MyFolder/MyFile.pdf");
```

You can use "../" for relative paths.